# How to calculate sin(alpha) = a in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, math

How can I calculated the angle in formula: sin(alpha) = a if I known a before.

Like example: sin(alpha) = 0.021 => alpha ?

Anybody can help me code the script to find out alpha value (angle)?

Thanks!

Comment: How would you do it in real life?

Comment: Look for an inverse sine (or arc sine) function - probably in the `math` module.

Comment: Look at the [asin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions) in the math module. `math.asin(0.021)` will give you one possible value of `alpha` in radians, but there are infinitely many other possible values as well.

Comment: @Loocid I use it to rotate distorted image when scanning.

Comment: @RoryDaulton It's working. First i use math.asin(0.021) to get radians value and then i convert from radians value to degrees value. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with Math module. Here is code:

```
import math
# To calculate 90 radian
a = math.sin(90*(math.pi)/180)
print(a)
# 1.0
b = math.asin(1.0)*180/(math.pi)
print(b)
# 90.0
```

It works.